# i Store JWT Token Cookies in but it not work

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, token, bearer-token

//login user and athenticate user

exports.userLogin = async (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;

```
try {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: email }).select('+password');
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid Email" });
  } 
  else if (user.password !== password) 
  {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid password" });
  }
   else {
    const token = user.getJwtToken()
    const options = 
    {
        expires:new Date(Date.now()+process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME*24*60*60*1000),
        httpOnly:true,
        Secure:true
    }
    res.status(201).cookie('token',token,options).json({
      token: token,
      user:user
    });
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log("something went wrong: " + err.message);
}
```

};

I Store token in cookie but its not work i check the token in cookie its empity

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario using `jsonwebtoken`, `express` in my system and able to see the cookie in the response headers. Maybe the problem is with the method `user.getJwtToken()` in line no. 11. It would be great if you add a log below line 11 and check the value of `token` whether you're getting any value or not.

Tried with the below and it worked fine.

```js
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

const start = (port) => {
    try {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`Api up and running at: http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit();
    }
};

start(3333);

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: 7, role: 'captain' }, 'TEST_JWT');
    return res
        .status(201)
        .cookie('token', token, {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
        })
        .json({ message: 'Logged in successfully!!!' });
});
```

[image: Set-cookie]

And also, it is not suggestible to show `Invalid Email` when the email is not present and `Invalid Password` when the password doesn't match as it might lead to security concerns whether a particular user is using the application or not. So, better to use something like `Invalid Email or Password` when either of the above cases is `true`.

```js
if (!user || user.password !== password) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid Email or Password" });
}
```